# Google Calendar API v3 always returns BadRequest when creating events

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I created a shared calendar and want to add events to the calendar.

I created a project and set up a Service Account `xxx@xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com`.

Then I shared the calendar to the Service Account as **owner**.

Then I noticed

> Service Account must manually add shared calendar

as described here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62232361/298430 and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148804709

So I wrote a code:

```
 @Test
  fun addCalendarToServiceAccount() {

    val calList1: CalendarList = calendar.calendarList().list().execute()
    logger.info("calList1 = {}", calList1)

    val inserted = calendar.calendarList().insert(CalendarListEntry().setId(calendarId)).execute()
    logger.info("inserted = {}", inserted)

    val calList2: CalendarList = calendar.calendarList().list().execute()
    logger.info("calList2 = {}", calList2)
  }
```

It works perfectly. When first called, I can see `calList1` is empty, and `calList2` contains something.

Then I manually insert one event to the calendar (with google calendar WEB UI), I want to check if I can retrieve the event:

```
@Test
  fun listEvents() {
    val events: Events = calendar.events().list(calendarId).execute()
    logger.info("events = {}", events)
    events.items.forEachIndexed { index, e ->
      logger.info("Event [index = {}] , event = {}", index, e)
    }
  }
```

It also works.

```
{
   "accessRole":"owner",
   "defaultReminders":[

   ],
   "etag":"\"xxx\"",
   "items":[
      {
         "created":"2020-08-17T17:51:21.000Z",
         "creator":{
            "email":"xxx@gmail.com"
         },
         "end":{
            "date":"2020-08-20"
         },
         "etag":"\"xxx\"",
         "htmlLink":"https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=xxx",
         "iCalUID":"xxx@google.com",
         "id":"xxx",
         "kind":"calendar#event",
         "organizer":{
            "displayName":"xxx",
            "email":"xxx@group.calendar.google.com",
            "self":true
         },
         "reminders":{
            "useDefault":false
         },
         "sequence":0,
         "start":{
            "date":"2020-08-19"
         },
         "status":"confirmed",
         "summary":"xxx  test1",
         "transparency":"transparent",
         "updated":"2020-08-18T01:07:54.441Z"
      }
   ],
   "kind":"calendar#events",
   "nextSyncToken":"xxx",
   "summary":"xxx",
   "timeZone":"Asia/Taipei",
   "updated":"2020-08-18T01:07:54.688Z"
}
```

Then I want to programmatically insert something, like the API example shows:

```
@Test
  fun testInsertEvent() {
    val now = LocalDateTime.now().withSecond(0).withNano(0)
    val zoneId = ZoneId.of("Asia/Taipei")
    val fromDate = Date.from(now.atZone(zoneId).toInstant())
    val endDate = Date.from(now.plusMinutes(60).atZone(zoneId).toInstant())

    val event = Event()
      .setSummary("Google I/O 2015")
      .setLocation("800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103")
      .setDescription("A chance to hear more about Google's developer products.")
      .setStart(EventDateTime().setDate(DateTime(fromDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone(zoneId))))
      .setEnd(EventDateTime().setDate(DateTime(endDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone(zoneId))))

    logger.info("before insert event : {}", event)

    val eventResult: Event = calendar.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute()
    logger.info("eventResult = {}", eventResult)
  }
```

I can see the client truly POST to google'e endpoint:

[image: Logs caught by IDEA]

The body is:

```
{
   "description":"A chance to hear more about Google's developer products.",
   "end":{
      "date":"2020-08-18T11:32:00.000+08:00"
   },
   "location":"800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103",
   "start":{
      "date":"2020-08-18T10:32:00.000+08:00"
   },
   "summary":"Google I/O 2015"
}
```

But google just replied 400 BadRequest, without any further description:

```
2020-08-18 10:32:15.974 [main] INFO  c.g.a.c.h.HttpResponse - -------------- RESPONSE --------------
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Alt-Svc: h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
Server: ESF
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Tue, 18 Aug 2020 02:32:15 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Referer
Vary: X-Origin
Vary: Origin
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

2020-08-18 10:32:15.980 [main] INFO  c.g.a.c.u.LoggingByteArrayOutputStream - Total: 171 bytes
2020-08-18 10:32:15.980 [main] INFO  c.g.a.c.u.LoggingByteArrayOutputStream - {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badRequest",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}
```

I am using the same *calendar* instance, can successfully `addCalendarToServiceAccount()` (as `owner`)  and `listEvents()`.
But what goes wrong when inserting an event? Did I miss anything?

Other fields are initialized as follows:

```
  @Value("\${google.calendar.id}")
  private lateinit var calendarId: String

  @Value("\${google.calendar.apiKey}")
  private lateinit var apiKey : String

  private val httpTransport: HttpTransport by lazy {
    GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport()
  }

  private val jacksonFactory: JsonFactory by lazy {
    JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance()
  }

  private val saCredentials: GoogleCredentials by lazy {
    javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/chancer-d1de03c4c25a.json").use { iStream ->
      ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(iStream)
        .createScoped(listOf(
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
          *CalendarScopes.all().toTypedArray()
        ))
    }.apply {
      refreshIfExpired()
    }
  }


  private val requestInitializer: HttpRequestInitializer by lazy {
    HttpCredentialsAdapter(saCredentials)
  }

  private val calendar: Calendar by lazy {
    Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, jacksonFactory, requestInitializer)
      .build()
  }
```

Environments:

```
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <kotlin.version>1.4.0</kotlin.version>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.30.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-calendar</artifactId>
      <version>v3-rev20200610-1.30.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
      <version>0.21.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: val eventResult: Event = calendar.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute()
      where are you setting calendarId?

Comment: h @DaImTo , it's defined in `application.properties` , and injected to the class , as shown in my code `@Value("\${google.calendar.id}")
  private lateinit var calendarId: String` . The value is shared across all my test methods , including `listEvents()` which works correctly.  The value is `3fxxxxxxxxggc@group.calendar.google.com`

Comment: Do a calendar.get and make sure thats the right calendar id and you have access to it.

Comment: are you sure thats the full body you are sending i can almost see in your image that you are sending Id.   Couldnt you post the text and not an image?

Comment: Hi @DaImTo . In my `addCalendarToServiceAccount()` , I can see log of inserted = ... some JSON object , with `"accessRole":"owner"` , `"id":"3fgnxxxxdggc@group.calendar.google.com"` , the ID is identical. I can also `calendar.acl().list(calendarId).execute()` and can see my SA `"user:xxx@xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com" `has `"role":"owner"`

Comment: Hi @DaImTo . Here is the log https://gist.github.com/smallufo/517ca41f45bdcaa400e053a96475c98e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You need to use `start.dateTime` and `end.dateTime` rather than `start.date` and `end.date`*

#### Fix:

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#request-body):

> `end.date`:   The date, in the format "yyyy-mm-dd", if this is an all-day event.
>
> `end.dateTime`: The time, as a combined date-time value (formatted according to RFC3339). A time zone offset is required unless a time zone is explicitly specified in **timeZone**.
>
> `start.date`: The date, in the format "yyyy-mm-dd", if this is an all-day event.
>
> `start.dateTime`: The time, as a combined date-time value (formatted according to RFC3339). A time zone offset is required unless a time zone is explicitly specified in **timeZone**.

Therefore, you need to change your date & time setting method from:

```
EventDateTime().setDate(DateTime(fromDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone(zoneId))))
```

to:

```
EventDateTime().setDateTime(DateTime(fromDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone(zoneId))))
```

Which will change the request body to:

```
{
  "description": "A chance to hear more about Google's developer products.",
  "end": {
      "dateTime": "2020-08-18T11:32:00.000+08:00" // modified
  },
  "location": "800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103",
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2020-08-18T10:32:00.000+08:00" // modified
  },
  "summary": "Google I/O 2015"
}
```

You can see the documentation for this method [here](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-services-calendar/latest/com/google/api/services/calendar/model/EventDateTime.html#setDateTime-com.google.api.client.util.DateTime-).

#### References:

- [Events: insert | Calendar API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)
- [RFC 3339 - Date and Time on the Internet: Timestamps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339)
- [EventDateTime (Calendar API v3-rev20200610-1.30.10)](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-services-calendar/latest/com/google/api/services/calendar/model/EventDateTime.html#setDateTime-com.google.api.client.util.DateTime-)

Comment: Well , I thought of this problem , but it is processed by google itself library. I cannot escape it. Even I try this `val startDateTime = DateTime("2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00")
` , it still outputs  `"start":{"date":"2015-05-28T09:00:00.000-07:00"}`

Comment: It's interesting Google's DateTime itself output milliseconds in RFC3339 : 
https://github.com/googleapis/google-http-java-client/blob/1b4ad2814d5f7f35032841cac81b38c525dc08bf/google-http-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/util/DateTime.java#L202

Comment: You need to use `EventDateTime().setDateTime()` not `.setDate()`. It requires a dateTime object, not a date. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks . it works . the `setDate` really confuses me.